# Update Opportunity custom field based on OpenActivities (Tasks and Events)

Tags: opportunity, tasks

I need to update a custom field (Next_Activity_Date__c) on Opportunity with next closest Date from Event or Task which is added to current Opportunity.

Example:
When a user has logged a Task/Event, and it's related to Opportunity - then get closest ActivityDate from OpenActivities and set it to Opportunity.Next_Activity_Date__c

This SOQL request can get all OpenActivities from current Oportunity

```
Opportunity oppActivities = [SELECT (SELECT ActivityDate FROM OpenActivities ORDER BY ActivityDate ASC) FROM Opportunity WHERE id = :oppId];
```

How to implement this by not writing two similar triggers on Task & Event objects?

```
trigger EventTrigger on Event (after insert, after update) {
    Opportunity[] oppToUpdate = new Opportunity[]{};

    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
        for(Event e : Trigger.new) {
            if(e.WhatId != null && e.WhatId .getSobjectType().getDescribe().getName() == 'Opportunity') {
                Opportunity opp = OpportunityHelper.getOpenActivities(e.WhatId);
                
                if(opp.OpenActivities.size() > 0) {
                    opp.Next_Activity_Date__c = opp.OpenActivities.get(0).ActivityDate;
                } else {
                    opp.Next_Activity_Date__c = null;
                }
                oppToUpdate.add(opp);
            }
        }
    }
    if(oppToUpdate.size() > 0) {
        update oppToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do this without code, or are you asking how to do this without duplicating code?

Comment: If you know how to implement this without code - please, share your solution. And the main question was - 'how to do this without duplicating code'
Currently, I have two triggers doing the same thing but on different objects

Answer (score 0):

As triggers, what you need is a common class to deduplicate your code (the Don't Repeat Yourself principle), something like:

```
public class OpportunityNextActivityDate {
  public static void execute(sObject[] records) {
    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(sObject record: records) {
      Id whatId = (Id)record.get('WhatId');
      if(whatId?.getSObjectType() == Opportunity.sObjectType) {
        oppIds.add(whatId);
      }
    }
    if(oppIds.isEmpty()) {
      return;
    }
    Opportunity[] opps = [SELECT Next_Activity_Date__c, (SELECT ActivityDate FROM OpenActivities ORDER BY ActivityDate ASC NULLS LAST) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :oppIds];
    Opportunity[] updatedOpps = new Opportunity[0];
    for(Opportunity record: opps) {
      if(!record.OpenActivities.isEmpty() && record.Next_Activity_Date__c != record.OpenActivities[0].ActivityDate) {
        updatedOpps.add(new Opportunity(Id=record.Id, Next_Activity_Date__c = record.OpenActivities[0].ActivityDate));
      }
    }
    update updatedOpps;
  }
}
```

Then, in your triggers, you just call the method:

```
trigger EventTrigger on Event (after insert, after update) {
  OpportunityNextActivityDate.execute(Trigger.new);
}
```

---

```
trigger EventTrigger on Task (after insert, after update) {
  OpportunityNextActivityDate.execute(Trigger.new);
}
```

---

You can also do this with Process Builder, but you'll need two Processes instead of Triggers, and ideally you'd use a flow with basically the same technique as this code: query the opportunity record's open activities, then grab the first date, if applicable, and update the Opportunity records.